# Undefined function 'imgaussfilt' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

first of all I'm sorry for the silly question but I'm a newbie in matlab. I have this program:

```
Efs =  double(imread('path\Immagine1.tif'));


% gaussian smooth for calibration image        
Efs = imgaussfilt(Efs,2);
```

that gives me this error:

Undefined function 'imgaussfilt' for input arguments of type 'double' Error in analisi3 (line 13) Efs = imgaussfilt(Efs,2);

I have tried to search and I have found very similar problems but I have not found the solution. Matlab has the last version, Efs is defined so I don't how this can give me error. Furthermore I have used this program in school pc and doesn't give any errors, so it is not a problem concerning the program.

Comment: What does the `ver` command return? Do you have the image processing toolbox available?

Comment: I'm using normal matlab i don't know of an image processing toolbox available. what is ver command?

Comment: Type it into your command window and it will tell you which toolboxes are available.

Comment: I haven't, i'm installing it.